# Is there a way to set my computer's resolution to 1366X768?

Tags: resolution, windows-8, acer-aspire

Because of this statement: "The resolution that supports all the features of Windows 8, including multitasking with snap, is 1366x768." found here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195134/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

I tried to set the resolution on my Acer Aspire 7741G-6426 from 1600X900 to 1366X768, but the only resolutions it offers me are:
1600X900 (recommended)
1280X768
1024X768

Is there a way to work around this constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your graphics driver and your monitor there might or might not be a workaround around that, but consider the following:

1)
The paragraph you are quoting from is titled `Minimum resolution and snap`. **Minimum**.

Now go to the next chapter:
`You can run Metro style apps on a screen`...`with a resolution of 2560x1600`.

To me that reads as: You need **at least** 1366x768 to enable all features.

2)
You really do not want to use a LCD screen at anything but its native resolution. If you do you either only use part of the screen (no stretching), resulting in black barso Or you stretch the image, resulting in an image with distortions (and headaches after a few hours of looking at that screen).

<sup>Exception: Fractions of native resolutions are fine. A 1080x1024 monitor at 640x480 or 320x240 is usually fine)</sup>

Comment: I would qualify your statement: You *usually* don't want an LCD at non-native resolution. Sometimes you have to work with software that only works correctly at a different resolution. But I agree, with Windows 8 itself, native resolution is the way to go.